# Rails 5 testing controller unfiltered params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have recently upgraded my application to Rails 5 and when I am testing my controller I am getting the following error:
`ActionController::UnfilteredParameters: unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash`.

My controller code looks like this:

```
def bid
  widget_mode = params.include?(:widget)
  if !@auction.published?
    redirect_to '/' #go to the homepage

  elsif @auction.third_party?
    redirect_to @auction.third_party_bidding_url

  elsif current_user && current_user.clerk? &&
        !@auction.listing? &&
        (@auction.items_count == 1 || params["section"] == "auction") &&
        !widget_mode
    redirect_to action: 'clerk', id: @auction.id, params: params.slice(:item, :section)
  else
    #  Make sure the auction is in firebase
    exists = @auction.rt_get('updated_at').body.to_i > 0 rescue false
    @auction.queue_realtime_update unless exists
  end
end
```

and my test code looks like this:

```
test "should redirect to powerclerk if multi item auction and params section = auction" do
  sign_in users(:clerk)
  a = auctions(:kenwood_dr)
  assert a.items.count > 1, "Expected auction to have more than one item"
  get :bid, params: {id: a.id, item: a.items.first.id, section: "auction"}
  assert_redirected_to "/clerk/1?item=1&section=auction"
end
```

I tried adding:
`params.permit(:item, :section, :id, :controller, :action, :widget)`
 to the beginning of my `bid` controller method and that didn't make a difference. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when calling `to_h` or `to_hash` on an instance of `ActionController::Parameters` that doesn't have any permitted keys ([documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_h)).

Since `ActionController::Parameters#slice` returns an instance of the same, this code does **not** give you a hash like it would seem: `params.slice(:item, :section)`.

In most cases you can use `permit` instead of `slice` on parameters instances. If you ever want to bypass the safe access whitelisting of `ActionController::Parameters` you can use `permit!` and use `ActionController::Parameters#slice`, or if you want to convert to a hash without sanitization you can use [to_unsafe_h](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#alias-method-i-to_unsafe_h).

Comment: thanks, @coreyward as stated below I finally figured that out shortly after posting this. Thanks for your feedback though :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by switching:

`redirect_to action: 'clerk', id: @auction.id, params: params.slice(:item, :section)`

to

`redirect_to action: 'clerk', id: @auction.id, params: params.permit(:item, :section)`