# ActionController::UnfilteredParameters in Controller#index unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash for redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

When I try to access http://127.0.0.1:3000/movies?ratings%5BG%5D=1&ratings%5BPG%5D=1&ratings%5BR%5D=1&sort_on_a_column=title I get the

> ActionController::UnfilteredParameters in MoviesController#index
> unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash error at redirect_to

```rb
def index
  @all_ratings = Movie.movie_ratings
  @ratings = Hash.new()

  # Filtering Movies

  if params[:ratings] != nil
   @checked_ratings = params[:ratings]

  elsif session[:ratings] != nil
    #  if any other request than filtering was performed, take the ratings stored in session during the previous request
    @checked_ratings = session[:ratings]
  else
    # All ratings are checked initially
    @all_ratings_hash = Hash[@all_ratings.map {|rating_name| [rating_name, 1]}]
    @checked_ratings = @all_ratings_hash
  end

  # Store the state of ratings filter to remember for any future request
  session[:ratings] = @checked_ratings
  session[:ratings] = session[:ratings]

  # Sorting Movies

  if (params[:sort_on_a_column]).nil?
    #  if any other request than sorting was performed, take the sorting_column stored in session during the previous request
    @column_to_be_sorted = session[:sort_on_a_column]
  else
    @column_to_be_sorted = params[:sort_on_a_column]
  end

  # Store the state of sort to remember for any future request
  session[:sort_on_a_column] = @column_to_be_sorted

  # Sorting boolean for index view
  @sort_by_title = @column_to_be_sorted == 'title'
  @sort_by_date = @column_to_be_sorted == "release_date"

  @movies = Movie.where(rating: @checked_ratings.keys).order( @column_to_be_sorted )

  if ( params[:sort_on_a_column].nil? and !(session[:sort_on_a_column].nil?) ) or ( params[:ratings].nil? and !(session[:ratings].nil?) )
    flash.keep
    redirect_to movies_path(sort_on_a_column: @column_to_be_sorted, ratings: @checked_ratings)
  end
end
```

I consulted [Rails 5 testing controller unfiltered params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576708/rails-5-testing-controller-unfiltered-params) but those methods didn't work for me and I am using Rails 6.1.3.1

Comment: What do your `params` look like?  If `params[:ratings]` or `params[:sort_on_a_column]` are a hash you can't path them through to the `movies_path` without using [Strong Parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) or bypassing the safety check with something like `to_unsafe_h`.

Comment: Yup, params[:ratings] is a hash. Couldn't we path them in older versions of rails tho? I tried "redirect_to movies_path(sort_on_a_column: @ column_to_be_sorted, ratings: @ checked_ratings.permit!)" and redirect_to movies_path(sort_on_a_column: @ column_to_be_sorted, ratings: @ checked_ratings.to_unsafe_h)" but neither of them worked